How to scrape table data from HTML with BeautifulSoup?
I have been trying to scrape a table from this website https://www.alphaquery.com/stock/aapl/earnings-history
but in no way I can achieve it. I can t even find the table.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_eps(ticker):
    url = f"https://www.alphaquery.com/stock/{ticker}/earnings-history"
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    
    # Attempt to more robustly find the table by checking for specific headers
    table = None
    for table_candidate in soup.find_all("table"):
        headers = [th.get_text(strip=True) for th in table_candidate.find_all("th")]
        if "Estimated EPS" in headers:
            table = table_candidate
            break
    if table:
        rows = table.find_all('tr')[1:6]  
        for row in rows:
            cells = row.find_all('td')
            if len(cells) >= 4:  # Ensure there are enough columns in the row
                try:
                    est_eps = cells[2].text.strip().replace('$', '').replace(',', '')
                except ValueError:
                    continue  # Skip rows where conversion from string to float fails
    else:
        print(f"Failed to find earnings table for {ticker}")

    return est_eps

# Example usage
ticker = 'AAPL'
beats = get_eps(ticker)
print(f'{ticker}  estimates {est_eps}')


Script finds the table and presents an output (may not the expected whole table, so please improve question, to get your expected format). There is no selenium invoked so I changed title and tags.

The favoured, sometimes easiest, way to scrape a table should lead you via pandas.read_html() it is using beautifulsoup under the hood:
Example
import pandas as pd

pd.read_html('https://www.alphaquery.com/stock/aapl/earnings-history')[0].replace('\$','',regex=True)





Announcement Date
Fiscal Quarter End
Estimated EPS
Actual EPS




0
2024-05-02
2024-03-31
1.51
1.53


1
2024-02-01
2023-12-31
2.09
2.18


...






36
2015-04-27
2015-03-31
0.55
0.58


37
2015-01-27
2014-12-31
0.65
0.77




However, to get just the estimates with your code you could work with yield instead of return:
        for row in rows:
            cells = row.find_all('td')
            if len(cells) >= 4:  # Ensure there are enough columns in the row
                try:
                    est_eps = cells[2].text.strip().replace('$', '').replace(',', '')
                    yield est_eps
                except ValueError:
                    continue  # Skip rows where conversion from string to float fails     
    else:
        print(f"Failed to find earnings table for {ticker}")

# Example usage
ticker = 'AAPL'
print(f'{ticker} estimates {list(get_eps(ticker))}')


it does not work, i get HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable

Common causes are a server that is down for maintenance or that is overloaded - Check additional details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503 and try again, all variants incl. selenium just work, if the server works correct.

Not sure how excessively you have already frequented the website / server from your environment. you may also have been recognised as a robot, because alternatively the 503 status code is also used to block web scrapers if they are identified and unwanted.
To avoid the 503 status code during web scraping, you should ensure that the server cannot identify the connections of the web scrapers.
